# Restrict to _vti_bin folder in all subsites for external SharePoint Sites

Tags: 2013, 2016, security

Hi as per company security compliance anonymous users should not access _vti_bin folder and services inside this folder.

- we have an external SharePoint site accessible for anonymous users.
  if I restrict access _vti_bin is impact to Site? or its allowed to anonymous users is any impact to security of site?

We enable the feature ViewFormPagesLockDown and also modify the Web.config file with the following XML element: but we have many sub sites and below configuration only applicable to certain site path only for example if I have subsite /en/news/_vti_bin/spsdisco.aspx below configuration not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_vti_bin is required to execute certain queries, which run under the user context (or anonymous). Locking this down isn't required as the code itself implements security.

This is lack of understanding of SharePoint on the security team's part.

Comment: Hi Trevor please can you share any articles or examples as code itself implement security from  Microsoft that i can show as evidence

Comment: Not sure the security settings are documented anywhere, but things an anonymous user might need to do is query ListData.svc in order to retrieve List items for display on a page. This is one example.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff521587(v=office.14)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff521586(v=office.14)#wcf-service-configuration

The SOAP services also reside in _vti_bin. There is a Lists.asmx SOAP service, as an example, though deprecated.